# Need R help with an HLM model with 2 level 1 (categorical) predictors and 1 level 2 (continuous) predictor

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, nested-models

I am trying to create a HLM in R where I have one outcome measure: Y; two dummy coded Level-1 predictors: A and B; and 1 continuous Level-2 predictor: Z.

Investigating a 3-way interaction with this specific nesting structure. Here's what I have:

`mod1 <- lmer(Outcome ~ A * B * Z + (1 + A | Z) + (1 + B | Z), data = Data)`

Is this capturing the hierarchical structure?

Is `mod2<- lmer(Outcome ~ A * B * Z + (1 + A * B | Z), data = Data)` different or capturing the same?

Basically, i want both A and B nested within Z and then to be able to look at the main effect of A, of B, of Z, the two way interactions (A*B, A*Z, B*Z), and the three-way. I'm having a hard time finding resources to help with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Why do you need to use a HLM? Are observations repeated within individuals, groups (teachers, schools, hospitals, etc), or something else? Can you post the result of `str(your_dataframe)`?

Comment: I need to use HLM because I am replicating a researchers analyses (not sure what software they used, it is not listed in the paper). Since I'm replicating, I don't have the data, but want to instead pre-register my analysis plan in the case that the replication reveals a null result. So basically, I am trying to create this HLM in R, but want to make sure it is specified correctly before registering it. @ErikRuzek

Comment: In order to help you, we need to know whether you are 1) repeatedly measuring individuals (longitudinal study) or 2) measuring individuals at one time point in a large number of units (e.g., schools, hospitals, houses, etc.). From your question and your response, it is not at all clear why you need HLM. HLM is relevant if you have one of the two conditions mentioned above. If not, you can use single level regression. Please tell us which of the two conditions you have.

Comment: Sorry about that @ErikRuzek! The design is 2 within-subjects factors (i.e, repeated measurements) - those are the Level 1 predictors. The Level 2 predictor is a between-subjects trait (participants at level 1 should be nested in the trait)